# Why do we say 'Comment était ta journée' and not 'Comment étais ta journée'

Tags: grammaire

I looked up the conjugation for [être](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-%C3%AAtre.html) and the word était is used for il/elle. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Consider that in English, one says "How _was_ your day?" and not "How _were_ your day?" as "your day" is the subject.

Comment: @Maroon this is basically right but taking a saying in one language to explain another one is a dangerous thing since certain languages may differ too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ta journée*** is the subject of ***était***.

Spoken French usually avoid the interrogative inversion which is formal so that makes:

> **Ta journée était** comment ?

or

> **Elle était** comment, ta journée ?

or

> Comment **elle était**, ta journée ?